# Write a listener for mongodb changes on server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, replicaset

I want to write a listener for changes to a collection in mongoDB for a nodejs app on the server side. I am using Robe to get the oplog. Here is my code:

```
  var co = require('co'),
    Robe = require('robe');

  co(function*() {
    // connect to db
    var db = yield Robe.connect('mongodb://localhost/');
    yield collection.addWatcher(function(collectionName, operationType, data) {
      console.log(collectionName)
    });
    var oplog = yield db.oplog();
    yield oplog.start();
    // listen for any operation on any collection
    oplog.onAny(function(collectionName, operationType, data) {
      console.log("something happened!!!")
    });
  })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
```

The documentation for Robe says that to get oplog, I need to connect to a replica set in mongoDB. I have been reading on the replica set on mongoDB and I have not been abe to make much sense of it. I did create a replica set called 'rs0'. I ran this command to start mongod:

```
         mongod --replset "rs0"
```

It is still not doing anything upon a DB change. Is this really the right way to do this?

Comment: Did you initiate the replica set?

Comment: I did and after that I corrected the name of the connection db. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Did you forget to initiate the replica set? Or did you initiate the replica set after seeing my comment?

Comment: Shall I add this as an answer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you start mongod instances with a replSet configuration, you will have to initiate the replica set with `rs.initiate()` command then add the replica set members.

When you are connecting to the replica set using driver clients, give the complete list of replica set mongod hosts, so that we will would be taking the advantage of automatic failover of replica sets.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You need to initiate the replset. In your MongoDb terminal, type:

```
        rs.initiate()
```

And also make sure that you are connecting to the correct host name for the db.